# Direct remote access (ssh) with Raspberry Pi running Ubuntu server 20.04.1

Tags: server, ssh, ethernet, raspberrypi, ip-address

I have problems determining the IP address of my Raspberry Pi for LAN-access between the Pi and my laptop.

**Equipment**:

- Laptop (Ubuntu desktop 20.04.1 LTS)
- Raspberry Pi 4 8GB (Ubuntu server 20.04.1 LTS) with keyboard, mouse & monitor for setup
- Ethernet switch and ethernet cable

**What I want to do:**
Direct ssh access to the server (Pi) with only an ethernet cable from the laptop to the Pi. The laptop is going to control a robot (Pi) using ROS. Going through an ethernet switch works too, but I have limited space for electronics on the robot run by the Pi (It's an underwater drone cast/welded in aluminium, so the space is definite and it isn't meant to be connected to the internet).

**What I've managed to do:**
Connect the Pi to the internet with ethernet, making the router assign it an IP address and managed to ssh into the Pi from my laptop over the same *internet* network.

**What I can't figure out:**
Connect to the Pi over LAN because it doesn't have an IP address unless connected to the internet. I have found the MAC address, but not sure how it can help me yet.

**What I've tried:**

- Use commands on the Pi to determine its IP address (`hostname -I` and `ifconfig`), but it only has an address when connected to the internet.
- Search for the Pi on the Local Area Network with a router not connected to the internet (but connected to both the laptop and the Pi) using the command `nmap` on the laptop with the IP addresses coming up on the laptop after using `ifconfig`. This gave no results, but I'm probably using it the wrong way.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: It sounds like you need to configure a static IP address for your Pi, since it's not connected to your gateway. Have a look at [Netplan](https://netplan.io/examples/) to configure a static IP.

Comment: That worked! Thank you!
I'll edit in the specific tutorial I used, but yeah, I needed to configure static IP addresses correctly.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please don't put SOLVED in the title and the solution in the question. This is a question answer site. Please use the button below to answer your own question and put the solution in the answer. Then after the wait period accept your answer as correct by clicking on the gray check mark ✔️ and turn it green ✅. This will mark the problem as solved and help others.

Comment: Alright, sounds good!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**: I needed to configure static IP addresses correctly. I used this tutorial: (https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-configure-static-ip-address-on-ubuntu-20-04/). The only thing I did differently were the exact addresses and changed "ens3" to "eth0" in the .yaml-file as it was how the ethernet connection appeared on my RPi. I can now ssh straight into my Pi through an ethernet cable without a switch.

Comment: I'm trying to achieve the exact same thing, however I would like the convenience of modifying the `network-config` file in the boot partition rather than relying on an initial DHCP ip to then modify to a static addresses. Do you know if this is possible?