# Headless Ubuntu 23.10 on Raspberry Pi 5

Tags: 23.10, rdp, headless

I have Ubuntu 23.10 running from an SSD attached to my Raspberry Pi 5. I would like to run the setup headlessly but if there is no monitor attached I cannot access it via Microsoft Remote Desktop. It appears that it does not load the graphic enviroment if no monitor is attached. I have even tried booting it with a monitor attached, established a RDP connection and then remove the monitor. That does not work either. I don't want to buy an HDMI virtual adapter if there is a way I can do this in software.

Comment: Use SSH/PuTTY rather than RDP

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Direct remote access (ssh) with Raspberry Pi running Ubuntu server 20.04.1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1299239/direct-remote-access-ssh-with-raspberry-pi-running-ubuntu-server-20-04-1) should also work with 23.10

Comment: Thanks for the above. If use SSH/Putty does that not limit me to console access? I am hoping to have access to a the desktop enviroment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to access a graphical environment, you need to be running a graphical environment. It is certainly possible to run a virtual graphical environment. I won't try to describe how because this isn't my expert area, but I suggest you look at running a VNC server on the Pi; e.g. TightVNC.

(With any luck, someone else will describe for you exactly how to do this. Apologies for the incompleteness of this "answer", but it may be enough to get you going.)

Comment: I have succeeded by using XRP and by stopping native sharing. Headless Ubuntu 23.10 from my Raspberry Pi 5 is very good.  I found this answer helpful. https://askubuntu.com/a/1492339/1762162